# Netscaler cannot access xpages mobile extention library 1.6.1 files

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, citrix, citrix-access-gateway, netscaler

Hi I have an xpages app that I have built using the mobile extension library controls. The ap works fine if you go straight to the notes server but as soon as we use netscaler to access we are getting errors accessing the extention libarary files. We have tracked it down to not being able to access these “/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js or whatever is in or around there.

For this post  http://www.intec.co.uk/domino-8-5-3-greater-power-over-dojo-thanks-ibm-for-your-work/ it looks like these files use the new OSGi plugin functionality and are contained in a jar file on the server rather than as separate files on the domino server. Any idea how we can get the citrix gateway to see these files and use them?
Thanks
Mel

Comment: Could you provide some source snippets?

Comment: you need to provide more information. Is this not loading on the client side? Do you see an error on developer tools? If so, how are you using the netscaler to front your website? Are you making any hostname/url transformations?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a Netscaler configuration problem to me. If [the manuals](http://support.citrix.com/product/ag/eev10.0/#tab-topic) don't help, [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) might be the better place to ask this question. As a wild guess: `/.` might be blocked by default since `../../../` is a popular path-traversal attack vector. Let us know how it goes

Comment: To my understanding /.ibmxspres is internal URL format translated inside XSP engine, and is never a output of http request. Am I wrong?.

Comment: Frantisek, you can access /xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js from HTTP. Here's an example from the OpenNTF dev server (running 9.0 so therefore Dojo 1.8.1): http://dev.openntf.org/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js

Comment: Neat, never tried :-). But my point was: in your XPages code this kind of url should not show up in resulting html, it is translated. So it seems they use this trick in links which are not properties of standard XSP components (resource, link...)

Comment: Anyway, it seems that mentioned url, is never translated - src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js". So yes, the only solution is to persuade admins to create Netscaler rules to allow ".ibmxspres" in urls.